# Spring Data JPA and SimpleJPA/SimpleDB

Tags: jpa, amazon-simpledb, spring-data

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify SimpleJPA as the persistence provider used by Spring-Data-JPA. I'm not a JPA expert so I hope this question isn't silly. Is it as easy as just specifying SimpleJPA's entity manager factory in the persistence.xml? I have yet to find anywhere online where someone has used Spring-Data-JPA to connect to Amazon's SimpleDB, I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally setting up your persistence provider is just a matter of setting up the `EntityManagerFactory` through your Spring context (in case you use the Spring container). Thus have a look at [how to configure `EntityManagerFactory` instances in Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup).

There might be the need to implement a custom `JpaVendorAdapter` to let Spring use the SimpleDB JPA implementation correctly. For some advanced functionality (e.g. using pagination with manually defined queries) we'd have to tweak the Spring Data JPA codebase a bit. If you'd like to see that supported feel free to open a ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA).

Comment: Thank you Oliver. As usual your answer has helped me achieve a successful implementation. Just a couple days ago we decided to switch over to MongoDB. I have found it to be a better solution for our project and using Spring Data with MongoDB has been absolutely seamless. Thank you for your answer and thank you for all the work you do on Spring Data.

Comment: Would there be an issue with the fact that SimpleJPA is JPA1.0 based?

Comment: I don't get the question? What is SimpleJPA?

Comment: JPA on top of AWS Simple DB. 
https://github.com/appoxy/simplejpa
It's third party, but amazon team endorses it, even using it for their demo project TravelLog. It is JPA1.0, not 2.0. Is there a way to make it play with spring-data-jpa?
Alternatively, I can use https://github.com/3pillarlabs/spring-data-simpledb

Comment: No, Spring Data JPA requires JPA 2.0. Besides the fact that I don't quite get why one would use a JPA based API to access a NoSQL store :). You effectively can use 2 or three annotation but everything else just hardly makes sense: what does a transaction rollback do in MongoDB?

Comment: I am not an expert on spring-orm, but I assumed spring can do its own transactions in memory, sending all the updates upon clicking commit.

Comment: Anyway I can also use Query interface. Most importantly, JPA provides portability, so if I want to switch to RDS, I can.

I guess my two choices are do a port of SimpleJPA on JPA2.0, or stick with spring-data-simpledb

Comment: "Most importantly, JPA provides portability". It promises, but it doesn't provide. If you ever ported an application from Hibernate to EclipseLink you know what I am talking about. However, using a hand full of annotations from JPA, doesn't mean you implement JPA, hence: no portability but a Potemkin village approach. Implying portability of code from a non-relational store to a relational one is a kind of weird thing to do in the first place. But, I didn't wanna side track this here :).

Answer (score 3):

I just found this project and got it working for our `Spring Data + SimpleDB` needs:

https://github.com/3pillarlabs/spring-data-simpledb

The documentation is pretty good and getting things up and running was pretty straight-forward. I was accessing SimpleDB via Spring Data with about 10 minutes of work.

Comment: I think the original poster was referring to JPA not SimpleDB but thanks for the pointer to this cool project! :)